# Azure Stream Analytics: Get Array Elements by name

Tags: sql, azure, azure-stream-analytics

I was wondering if it is possible for me to get the elements of the array by the name of property than the position. For example, this is my incoming data:

```
    {
    "salesdata": {
        "productsbyzone": {
            "zones": [{
                    "eastzone": "shirts, trousers"
                },
                {
                    "westzone": "slacks"
                },
                {
                    "northzone": "gowns"
                },
                {
                    "southzone": "maxis"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I intend to move this to a SQL database and I have columns within the database for each zone. The problem is that the order of different zones changes within each json. I was successfully using the following query until I realized that the position of the zones changes within each json:

```
WITH 
salesData AS
(
    SELECT
    (c.salesdata.productsbyzone.zone,0) as eastzone,
    (c.salesdata.productsbyzone.zone,1) as westzone,
    (c.salesdata.productsbyzone.zone,2) as northzone,
    (c.salesdata.productsbyzone.zone,3) as sourthzone,
    FROM [sales-data] as c
)
SELECT
eastzone.eastzone as PRODUCTS_EAST,
westzone.westzone as PRODUCTS_WEST,
northzone.northzone as PRODUCTS_NORTH,
southzone.southzone as PRODUCTS_SOUTH
INTO PRODUCTSDATABASE
FROM salesData
```

Need a way to reference these fields by the name rather than by the position.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend a solution: Use the [JavaScript UDF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-javascript-user-defined-functions) in the azure stream job to complete the columns sort.

Please refer to my sample:

***Input data(upset the order):***

```
{
    "salesdata": {
        "productsbyzone": {
            "zones": [{
                    "westzone": "slacks"  
                },
                {
                    "eastzone": "shirts, trousers"
                },
                {
                    "northzone": "gowns"
                },
                {
                    "southzone": "maxis"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

***js udf code:***

```
function test(arg) {
    var z = arg;
    var obj = {
        eastzone: "",
        westzone: "",
        northzone: "",
        southzone: ""
    }   
    for(var i=0;i<z.length;i++){
        switch(Object.keys(z[i])[0]){
            case "eastzone": 
                obj.eastzone = z[i]["eastzone"];
                continue;
            case "westzone": 

                obj.westzone = z[i]["westzone"];
                continue;
            case "northzone": 

                obj.northzone = z[i]["northzone"];
                continue;
            case "southzone": 
                obj.southzone = z[i]["southzone"];
                continue;
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

You can define the order you want in the `obj` parameter

***SQL:***

```
WITH 
c AS
(
    SELECT 
    udf.test(jsoninput.salesdata.productsbyzone.zones) as result
    from jsoninput
),
b AS
(
  SELECT 
    c.result.eastzone as east,c.result.westzone as west,c.result.northzone as north,c.result.southzone as south
    from c
)

SELECT
    b.east,b.west,b.north,b.south
INTO
    jaycosmos
FROM
    b
```

***Output:***

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you! I will try this and let you know.

Comment: @user2263025 Sure! waiting for your reply.

Comment: Perfect solution!! Thank you.

Comment: @everydaylearn You're welcome,you could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `GetArrayElement` to return array element then access to each property. Please refer the below query

```
WITH 
salesData AS
(
    SELECT
        GetArrayElement(zones,0) as z
        FROM [sales-data] as s
)

SELECT
    z.eastzone
    z.westzone
    z.northzone
    z.southzone
FROM PRODUCTSDATABASE
FROM salesData
```

Comment: Nope. Incorrect. This does not work. GetArrayElement with an index of 0 would only select 

{
  "eastzone": "shirts, trousers"
}